# Solution with MVC/WebApi and WCF - Authentications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have been assigned a old project that currently uses a WCF service.

The point is to update (more like starting fresh) the project to use ASP.NET MVC5 and Web API. The problem is that a 3rd party uses the WCF service, and they are probably not willing to make changes to their end of the communication.

The main function of the project is two basic, one is receive data, save it and just show the last status of several subjects and history graphs, and the other is to send data (turn on/off subjects).

My idea was to maintain the WCF Service (receive/send/save data) as is, just add it to new solution which consists of MVC and Web API (read data). **They need (I think) to be in the same project, because the final objective is to implement SignalR on the WCF Service, if possible.**

The main problem, is that the MVC and WebAPI are going to stay behind Authentication, but the WCF won't. At the moment when I try to test the WCF on the same project, it fails because it asks for a "Log in."

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost:50598/ServiceTest.svc If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error URI: http://localhost:50598/ServiceTest.svc Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:50598/ServiceTest.svc'. The content type text/html;
>   charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type
>   of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a
>   custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '?
>
> Log in.
>
> Usernamehttp://localhost:50598/ServiceTest.svc The HTML document does not
>   contain Web service discovery information.

I tried everything that I could find on the web. But couldn't find anything that would work.

My last consisted on fiddling with the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="UnsecuredBinding">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Management.ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Management.ServiceTest" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Management.ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLibrary.IService" bindingConfiguration="UnsecuredBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I also added routes.IgnoreRoute to RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc");
```

and tried to add this to Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;

   if (context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".svc"))
   {
      context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
   }
}
```

My questions:

1. If I migrate the WCF methods to WebAPI, will the client need to do any modifications on their end?
2. If yes, how can I integrate WCF on my MVC/WebAPI project, without being affected by Log In barrier.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to question 1, yes your clients would have to make modifications. WCF is SOAP/XML where as WebApi is REST/JSON(usually) for starters.
As for 2, if the WCF service is working fine, just leave it as it is. You don't need to include it in the project directly, simply use the "Add Service Reference" wizard in Visual Studio to make a client for interacting with it.
As a side note, the error you where experiancing was probably due to using the inbuilt IIS express instance with Visual Studio, which doesn't support running anonymous and authenticated applications at the same time, so your WCF service ended up with authentication enabled.